# Calculating the 95% CI for a 10-point increase in the independent variable in a logistic regression

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval

I am trying to calculate the 95% confidence interval for a 10-point increase in a continuous independent variable in a logistic regression. For a 1-point increase, the 95% CI would be exp(1*beta +/- 1.96*SE).  For a 10-point increase in the independent variable, would the 95% CI be exp(10*beta +/- 1.96*SE) or would it be exp(10*beta +/-10*1.96*SE)?

Comment: for a nonlinear model like a logistic regression, it's going to depend where you are increasing 10 points *from*.

Comment: The second one is correct (you can check by dividing the covariate by 10). Interpretation is hard in either way. It will give you a confidence interval for an *approximative* effect on the odds ratio. The approximation gets worse the larger the jump.

Comment: @JohnMadden That is not true of the odds ratio, which to some is the whole point of using it. It would be the case for differences in probabilities, but since OP refers to "beta" I assume they are interest in odds ratios.

Comment: @Noah oh ye that's an exp not a logit; big true

Comment: @MichaelM, thank you for your helpful answer. I tried this, and it worked against my calculations.

Comment: @Noah and John Madden thanks!